# How to get two id data from same table using codeigniter join funtion

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I  have  table  call  **jobs**  and  i  need to  get **jobs.user_iduser** and  **jobs.adminId** from same  table call **user**

I try this  code  it  output  only one user data only.

```
$this->db->from('jobs');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.iduser = jobs.user_iduser', 'left');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.iduser = jobs.adminId', 'left');
```

then  i try like  this it output  only one user data only.

```
$this->db->from('jobs');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.iduser = jobs.user_iduser', 'left');
$this->db->join('user as admin', 'admin.iduser = jobs.adminId', 'left');
```

Is there any way to achieve  this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$this->db->select('u.iduser as uiduser, ua.iduser as uaiduser and so  on');
 $this->db->from('jobs');
 $this->db->join('user u', 'u.iduser = jobs.user_iduser', 'left');
 $this->db->join ('user ua', 'ua.iduser = jobs.adminId', 'left');
```

In your case since the user joined in the first join is being replaced by the second join. So you need to try aliasing the tables.

Comment: Sir i  use this  code **`$query = $this->db->get();
        $query =   $query->result_array(); `**  get data output it  only out data using  column name. 
i try  you code  it still output one user info .

Comment: Thanks good sir for  your  help  . i change  your  code bit  **`$this->db->select('* ,admin.userNameFirst as adminNameFirst ,auser.userNameFirst as auserNameFirst'  );`** an  i get  full result  as  i  need.

Comment: Glad that your problem solved. Please accept the answer for the benefit of community users.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('jobs', 'user.iduser = jobs.user_iduser', 'left');
$this->db->join('jobs', 'user.iduser = jobs.adminId', 'left');
```

I don't exactly know the data in tables but `left join` in SQL means:

> Select all records from Table A *(user in above example)*, 
>   along with records from Table B *(jobs in above example)* for
>   which the join condition is met (if at all). **[Ref](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/)**

So, since you have said only one user data is being returned, with **`jobs`**  being the left table I am assuming the table **`jobs`** contains only one user data. Let me know if you don't follow me.

Comment: I found  solution  for  that  issue. Thanks   for  your  comment  sir.